# Display density: how about a compact view?

Tags: feature-request, design, user-interface, meta

Update 2021-12-07: I'm now making the same feature request for non-meta UI.

---

I see that Meta's UI has now much more white space than it used to:

[image]

vs.

[image]

Would it be possible to add a 'compact view' option, similar to what Gmail offers? (I'm also fine if we simply remove all those white space)

[image]

If interested, [some userscripts to fix the UI](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/3397/903).

Comment: The current SE design trend is toward more whitespace: recently launched sites (Workplace, Money, Graphic Design) have **copious** amounts of it.

Comment: Wow. You have a lot of mails in your inbox.

Comment: This is a design decision. You're allowed to have a preference for something else, but if you're going to ask for it to change, it would be helpful for you to explain why the current version doesn't work for you.

Comment: I'm just asking for an option to increase the display density. The reason why I don't like the new design is simply because it wastes too much space of my screen, which decreases my productivity.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt - I feel your pain, that extra spin of the mouse wheel really does hit productivity ;)

Comment: @Laura Explain than. IMHO new one is not better or worse - it's just how you are attached to it.

Comment: It makes a really big difference when viewing on a 768 tall monitor, which comes out to 664 of usable vertical area after subtracting the Windows 7 taskbar and the Firefox tabs and address bar. On the page you posted as an example, I can't even see the lower-left answers list at all, even after using the less info link. Designers should consider these all so common 768 tall laptop screens more than they already do.

Comment: isn't that the tuned white space gives the eyes more room to breath, therefore increasing your productivity? I know that getting rid of scrolling mouse is also sweat, but I think (or at least for me), this is a good trade off to not getting overload of information.