# Too small margins between user names on the timeline

Tags: bug, design, deleted-answers, moderators, timeline

[In the post timeline](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/328544/timeline), the margins between usernames are too small, especially when a moderator (with the additional displayed icon) has participated:

> [image]

Comment: It's line height, not margin, [this is how it looks like with 20px line height](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EnD27.png), for example.

Answer (score 1):

I'm voting to instead make that mod icon (and other possible icons) smaller. For once, SE decided not to have some [large amount of white space](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/229898/178179), and I'd prefer to keep the UI reasonably compact.